# C# record video from Skype using SKYPE4COMLib

Tags: c#, skype4com

Hi i am writting Skype recorder. 
In **SKYPE4COMLib** documentation i found methods how to record audio calls from microphone and headphones:

```
call.CaptureMicDevice[TCallIoDeviceType.callIoDeviceTypeFile] = path1;
call.OutputDevice[TCallIoDeviceType.callIoDeviceTypeFile] = path2;
```

But i can't find any examples how to record video from Skype.
Maybe someone had working with **SKYPE4COMLib** before or have any ideas how to record video?

Thanks.